# How do I get rows for a column and then sum the rows in a particular column in pandas

Tags: pandas

I am trying to get the rows from an existing dataset (Year) and calculate the number of Incidents and add it to a new table where I want to have the year and how many incidents occured. [Dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dc3Wh.png)

```
anti_social[anti_social['Year'] == 2008].count()['No Of Incidents']
```

The dataset has 1000s of rows

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you studied any tutorials? What is the code you currently have?

Comment: @KorayTugay #anti_social_2008 = anti_social[anti_social["Year"] == 2008]
anti_social[anti_social['Year'] == 2008].count()['No Of Incidents']

Comment: I think what you are looking for is `groupby` : https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
anti_social.groupby('Year').sum()
```

Comment: Thank you, this seems to have fixed a little

Comment: @SeanKane What do you mean a little?

Comment: I was looking to count the number of incidents which occur each year

Comment: Try using the `count()` method instead of `sum()`.

Comment: Thank you so much!